# Restore failed for server (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. While I am restoring database from backup file I got the error.

> Restore failed for Server 'WIN-TUT3YRM1MMN\SQLEXPRESS'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: RESTORE detected an error on page (44262:41495) in database "KBCLDBNEW" as read from the backup set. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I have tried restoring in new database but still gives the error. I am cannot find the what is the problem. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 7):

Try running `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` and see if you get more information about the failure.

You could also try running `RESTORE` with `CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR` and then run [`DBCC CHECKDB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
RESTORE DATABASE database_name 
FROM backup_device WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR
```

(i.e. running as TSQL rather than through SMO)

```
DBCC CHECKDB(N'databasename') WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS;
```

> Specifying WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR in a RESTORE statement attempts
>   to restore the database. However, there are many kinds of corruption
>   that prevent recovering a database. We strongly recommend that you
>   reserve using the CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR option until you have exhausted
>   all alternatives.

**All** backup strategies should include regular `DBCC CHECKDB` runs.

**Also NOTE:** You do not have a backup unless you periodically successfully test restores.

[Responding to SQL Server Restore Errors Caused by Damaged Backups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190952.aspx)